# SQL SELECT query From SELECT query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I encountered a small problem in my attempt on a database related to the classrooms of a school.I have a table with classrooms and their number of seats as in:

Table: classrooms

```
NAME     SEATS 
R1       20
R1       25
```

and a table associated to each classroom (R1,R2,R3) as in:

```
Table: R1
NAME   DATE        FREE
R1     11/6/2015   YES
R1     12/6/2015   NO

Table: R2
NAME   DATE        FREE
R2     11/6/2015   YES
R2     12/6/2015   YES
```

Is it possible to SELECT from "classrooms" the NAME (based on seats) and use the returned values as TABLE titles in another SELECT?

Something like:

```
SELECT NAME FROM (SELECT NAME FROM classrooms WHERE SEATS>20) WHERE DATE=11/6/2015 AND FREE=YES
```

The SELECT inside the brackets would return the names of the TABLES to which I apply the query for DATE and FREE.

Is that even possible?I would really appreciate any suggestion!

Comment: _"Is the following query correct?"_ You really ask _us_?

Comment: If you want to helped at least consider to provide sample data for both tables and desired output for your query in the tabular form.

Comment: You seem to be new to SQL, so you should read some tutorials/classes on SQL to get the basics.

Comment: I have edited the post.Please take another look.

Comment: @user3605321 - edits after closing will automatically move your question into a review queue for reopening.  And thank you for removing your Programmers version of this question.

Answer (score 3):

I think there is only one answer: execute your query in the client (ie Management Studio). The select query will have no impact for your tables so don't worry and try yourself.

Comment: It's obvious that the query doesn't work since he's filtering in the `Where` by columns that weren't selected in the sub-query(only `name`). There's also a right parenthesis without a left. But apart from that the question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have the original select statement? That does not seem necessary...

```
SELECT name FROM classrooms 
   WHERE type="xx" AND seats>="xx") 
   WHERE day="xx" AND class="xx" 
   AND free="xx"
```

You could do the same thing with that unless you need the subquery for some reason I can't see.